# Selenium ChromeDriver on azure

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, azure-web-app-service

I just used Selenium ChromeDriver in my project and it was working fine on local but when I tried to deploy my app on azure it gets this

```
ERROR: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities capabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
```

I have tried so many solutions but nothing is working

this is my code:

```
var chromeOptions = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "Application", "chrome.exe");
string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "chromedriver", "chromedriver.exe");

using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(path, chromeOptions))
```

Also I have tried to use Docker and got me this

```
ERROR: /root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/122.0.6261.69/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HN1NJ3AU4944", Request id "0HN1NJ3AU4944:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:46023/
         at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start()
```